# angularjs ng-view not working with External templateUrl

Tags: cross-browser, angularjs

I want to take an angular application that works fine on my own domain and 'embed' it into several other sites.

The app uses partials with the ng_view directive so that the only thing i need to do to 'inject' my app into one of my pages is...

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-view></div>
```

My app looks like this...

```
angular.module('myapp', ['myapp.filters', 'myapp.services', 'myapp.directives', 'ui']).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.otherwise({templateUrl: 'partials/mainTemplate.html', controller: myController});
}]);
```

this works fine, but when I try to 'inject' the app into another site, In addition to externalizing the script references, I changed the app to look like this...

```
angular.module('myapp', ['myapp.filters', 'myapp.services', 'myapp.directives', 'ui']).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.otherwise({templateUrl: ''http://mydomain.com/partials/mainTemplate.html', controller: myController});
}]);
```

But it doesn't work... no errors, no nothing, it just doesn't render my app.

Any ideas?  are external partial references allowed?...  is the browser being over-protective? Should I take a completely different approach??

Comment: I don't think the http partial reference is allowed.

Comment: My guess would be that your running into issues with the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) but this should be producing errors in your Javascript console (at least in Webkit).

Comment: Michael, did you discover a solution to this problem?  I'm running into a similar issue.

Comment: You have two `''` before url, is that a typo or you have that in your code?

Comment: I think you need to leverage ngInclude to solve this problem, checkout the docs here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) on mydomain.com in order to get the view. And, as bUKaneer says, you have to add mydomain.com in the $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist

Comment: This sounds right to me although in the end I think I ended up using grunt and html2js to package all my templates into a big js file. More practical